# Random variables $X,Y$ such that $E(X|Y)=E(Y|X)$ a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that $E(|X|), E(|Y|)<\infty$ and $E(X|Y)=E(Y|X)$ a.s. Then is it true that $X=Y$ a.s. ? If this is not true in general, what happens if we also assume $X,Y$ are identically distributed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true at all.

Let $X, Y$ be indepedently, identically distributed.

$$
\mathbb{E}(X ) = \mathbb{E}(X | Y ) = \mathbb{E}(Y|X ) = \mathbb{E}(Y )
$$

but this does not mean $P(X = Y) = 1$.

---

Suppose $X, Y \overset{iid}{\sim} Normal(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Note that $P(Z = 0) = 0$, where $Z := X -Y$, because $Z \sim N(0, 2\sigma^2)$ is a continuous R.V.

So the probability measure of the event $X = Y$ is $0$, not $1$ (as in **almost sure** case).

But since $X, Y$ are independent,

$$
\mu = \mathbb{E}(X ) =   \mathbb{E}(X | Y ) = \mathbb{E}(Y|X )  = \mathbb{E}(Y )
$$

Comment: You mean to say $E(X|Y)$ is a constant random variable !? Also I would like to point out that $E(X|X)=X$ ...

Comment: @user521337 Yes, since $X$ is independent of $Y$.

Comment: Also, $Z$ is $N(0 , \sigma^2)$ ...

Comment: @user521337 No, $Z \sim N(0, 2 \sigma^2)$. For the variance, check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917276/distribution-of-the-difference-of-two-normal-random-variables)

Comment: again ... I would like to point out that $E(X|X)=X$ and not $E(X)$ ...

Comment: @user521337 you're right. Edited.

Comment: @user521337 I believe you're stuck at the fact that $\mathbb{E}(X | Y)$ is not random. But since $\mathbb{E} (X)= \mathbb{E}(X | Y=y), \forall y$, it is true that $\mathbb{E}(X | Y)$ is not random.